# SVN on command prompt, need to pass username argument with spaces

Tags: batch-file, svn, command-line, command-prompt

I am writing a batch script that will automate setting up a project.  One thing I need to do is to checkout from SVN....easy right?

Well, the issue is that username has spaces in it! (Don't ask me why)  When I try `svn co https//url/path --username user name`, the command asks for password from user and not "user name"

Hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: Did you think about quotes? Very devious, but possible ...

Comment: Have you tried `--username user\ name` insted of `--username user name`?

Comment: I have tried quotes and doesn't work and "user\" name logs in as "user\" =(

Comment: Voting to close as offtopic because this is just a typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have spaces in your argument enclose them in quotes:

For example:

```
--username "user name"
```

Comment: @HoaTheNguyen, please show the command you run and the output you receive.

Comment: @HoaTheNguyen its quotes, not spaces.

Comment: Sorry meant quotes, brain fart, will screen shot for you Amnon

Comment: nvm I had a brain fart, double quotes works, THANKS!